# Anyone knows what is a kinspect?

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks

Anyone knows what is a kinspect? Is it related to somewhere memory leaks?

Someone please help me, if you'll know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't find "kinspect" in the [FreeBSD and Linux Kernel Cross-Reference](http://fxr.watson.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to google it's a typo'd version of [Linspect](http://www.linspect.com/)